# XSD validation restriction of maxoccurs

Tags: xsd, xsd-validation

Hi I have this kind of XML

I would like to write an XML that validates this data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Entry attribute1="value1" attribute2="Value2">
    <subEntry tagX="xValue1" tagy="yValue"/>
</Entry>
```

but doesn't validate

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Entry attribute1="value1" attribute2="Value2">
    <subEntry tagX="xValue1" tagy="yValue"/>
    <subEntry tagX="xValue1" tagy="yValue"/>
</Entry>
```

I would like to restrict the number of subEntries:

The maxOccurs of sequence don't check the number of subEntries.

The XSD is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:element name="Entry">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="subEntry"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute1 name="dateEmission" type="xs:dateTime" use="required"/>
            <xs:attribute2 name="emetteur" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="Entry">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute name="tagX" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
            <xs:attribute name="tagy" type="xs:decimal" use="optional"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add maxOccurs on the element declaration. Change it to below

```
<xs:sequence>
     <xs:element ref="subEntry" maxOccurs="1" />
</xs:sequence>
```